# Not able to jump to the page after login.php login

Tags: php, session

draw.php

```
<?php
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['user_id']) || empty($_SESSION['user_id'])) {
     header("Location: login.php");
     exit;
}
if (isset($_SESSION['username']) && !empty($_SESSION['username'])) {
     $username = $_SESSION['username'];
} else {
     echo "User account not obtained";
     exit;
}
?>
```

login.php

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
     $username = $_POST['username'];
     $password = $_POST['password'];
     $sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = '$username' AND password = '$password'";
     $result = $conn->query($sql);
     if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
         $member = $result->fetch_assoc();
         $_SESSION['user_id'] = $member['user_id'];
         $_SESSION['username'] = $member['username'];
        
         session_start();
         header("Location: draw.php");
         exit;
     } else {
         echo "Login failed: wrong account or password";
     }
}
$conn->close();
ob_end_flush();
?>
```

The platform I use is 000webhost.com, which does not support modifying php.ini I am sure I have entered the correct account and password But when I press the login button, the page redirects back to login.php When I deliberately enter the wrong account password, it will prompt an error When I cancel the verification function in draw.php, I can correctly jump to the page to draw.php when logging in What information do I need to correct or provide? Thanks

Comment: session_start(); must be placed **before** you use the $_SESSION variable

Answer (score 0):

start session in start of file 'login.php' ,
session must start before any request send or receive

and i suggest you encrypt password before save in database

Comment: I experimented with the code you provided, but the screen still stays in login.php

Comment: Passwords should be hashed, not encrypted

Answer (score 0):

```html
<?php
session_start();
//import your database cconnection file
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
     $username = $_POST['username'];
     $password = $_POST['password'];
     $sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = '$username' AND password = '$password'";
     $result = $conn->query($sql);
     if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
         $member = $result->fetch_assoc();
         $_SESSION['user_id'] = $member['user_id'];
         $_SESSION['username'] = $member['username'];
        
         
         header("Location: draw.php");
         exit;
     } else {
         echo "Login failed: wrong account or password";
     }
}
$conn->close();
ob_end_flush();
?>
```